# Error while using fopen saying 'Inavlid file identifier'

Tags: matlab

I'm having problems using `fopen`. The error message says:

```
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
```

I tried the methods suggested for the same question asked like freeing up space and adding permission to fopen but they didn't work. I'm not even able to execute just a single line of code of

```
fid= fopen('text.txt','w')
```

which gives `fid= -1`.

Please help...

Comment: I just had a similar issue 5 minutes ago (no kidding) and the problem was I was trying to write a file on an external hard drive and it was not working because of permissions I guess. Once I changed the location to some folder on my desktop it worked; that's worth a try I think.

Comment: what is your current work directory? does `text.txt` already exists? do you have writing permissions to the current work directory?